# Bootstrap 3 - Form Submitted to "_blank"

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Bootstrap form in Bootstrap. What I have done is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Register a New User</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>

    <form role="form" method="POST" target="register">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I have submit, it directly goes to another new bl;ank page and submit the form data there, but I like to submit in the same page.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
target="register" is your issue. 
Just remove the target="register" or set the target="" from the form.
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
    <form role="form" method="POST" target="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to define an `action` in the `form` tag

```
action="yourFile.php"
```

Add an action in the form as:

```
 <form role="form"  action="yourFile.php" method="POST" target="register">
```

Answer (score 0):

`target="register"` is your issue. IF there is no window/frame with that name, then it will open a new window. Either remove it, or target a window that is already open.